# Why the result appears same even after changing code in JSP and HTML?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, tomcat

I am using JSP,HTML,SQL server 2005 and Tomcat server. 
My question is some times even I change code the result appears same as before. It remains same after closing everything but if I change the file name the result got updated. 
Why this happens I really don't understand?

Comment: Can you give any example (code would be great) of what you updated and what did not change? Thanks.

Stackoverflow does a really good job of providing suggestions when you type a question but I think it will take time for this site to read (and display) what is going on in people's mind while asking a question ;-)

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for? Browser caching is the first that comes to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened with me also, mostly when running project from IDE( e.g. Eclipse) that changes in JSP do not get reflected.

By default tomcat is started in development mode, which means JSP-derived servlets recompiled when a change is detected.

Tomcat compares the modification date of the JSP file with the modification time of the compiled class corresponding to this JSP, and if more recent, it re compiles on the fly before executing it.So, This is how tomcat compiles JSP on the fly.

> Why this happens I really don't understand?

When you rename a JSP and run, It find new name and compiles the JSP in to servlet.

There could be another reason which is client side caching when you may not see newer version of pages. Simply hitting CTRL+R / CTRL + F5 or clearing cache often works.

In JSP, you can add `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">` no to cache page.

P.S.
Though, I got your question, I would recommend to provide proper description.

Comment: Yup! Sorry for the improper description. Thank you so much for your reply.